# jasper report with mongodb in aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports

I have a collection named `Stock_Data_Revise_Nyse` which has some relevant data and i am making reports using jasper ireporter but when i execute this given query it only returns me **value field** with appropriate value and rest `_id.Date,_id.Stock` returns `null`.

This query is running perfectly fine in **Mongo Shell**.

noticed:- If i use single group by then aggregation works fine in Jasper but when i use double group by like i have used here it returns null for that field.

I have searched many forums but hardly found any answer.

Any Kind Of Help Would Be Appreciated.

```js
{ runCommand: {
    aggregate : "Stock_Data_Revise_Nyse",
    pipeline : [
        {$project:{Symbol_1:1,Name:1,Change:1,Date:{$substr:["$UTC_Timestmp",0,10]}}},
        {$match:{"Date":"16-01-2013"}},
        {$group:{
            _id:{Date:"$Date",Stock:"$Symbol_1"},
            value:{$sum:"$Change"}
        }},
        {$sort:{"value":-1}},
        {$limit:5}
    ]
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're using an old version of MongoDB Connector (v0.5.0, which is the only version available on [MongoDB Connector download page](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/mongodb-connector/releases)).

Download [JasperSoft Studio](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio) v2.0.1 or later, then use the included file `plugins/com.jaspersoft.studio.data.mongodb_2.0.1.jar` as your dependency to replace the old MongoDB Connector v0.5.0.

You can also get this artifact using Maven (we Bippo/Soluvas are only providing the service to host commonly needed files in a Maven repository):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jaspersoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.jaspersoft.studio.data.mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>bippo-nexus-public</id>
        <url>http://nexus.bippo.co.id/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```