# Which jar contains com.jaspersoft.mongodb.MongoDbConnection

Tags: java, mongodb, jasper-reports

I want to create a connection in jasper like

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
MongoDbConnection connection = new MongoDbConnection(mongoURI,null,null);
parameters.put(MongoDbDataSource.CONNECTION, connection);
```

Could anyone please tell me which jar file contains the following class

```
com.jaspersoft.mongodb.MongoDbConnection
```

It would be better if you can give me maven groupId and artifactId.

Comment: The application *Jaspersoft Designer* is using *js-mongodb-datasource-x.jar*. For example, the version 1.1.2 of designer contains *js-mongodb-datasource-0.9.3.jar* file with *com.jaspersoft.mongodb.connection.MongoDbConnection* class

Comment: groupId=com.jaspersoft.connectors.mongodb, artifactId=js-mongodb-datasource

Comment: The link to the connector: [MongoDB Connector](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/mongodb-connector/releases). For more details see the [jasper report with mongodb in aggregation framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387099/jasper-report-with-mongodb-in-aggregation-framework) post

Comment: Thank you, Alex, very much. It's very helpful

Comment: Hi Alex, According to the link you provided I added com.jaspersoft.studio.data.mongodb_5.6.0.final.jar. But I cannot find MongoDbConnection class. My code was Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
MongoDbConnection connection = new MongoDbConnection(mongoURI, null, null);
parameters.put(MongoDbDataSource.CONNECTION, connection);
       JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("test.jrxml");
           JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap(), connection); How to fill report without connection

Answer (score 0):

1)Download the source files and jar files for mongodb connector from here:

http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/mongodb-connector/releases

2)Add them into your java project or create a new one. You can find the MongoDbConnection.java in the com.jaspersoft.mongodb.MongoDbConnection package.

Cheers.

Comment: Is this present in maven repository? If yes, please share a link. Also I dont see jar file at http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/mongodb-connector/releases